# Why are some attributes of instances being modified when appending to a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having an issue where instance attributes are being changed unexpectedly when I add instances to a list. New Gem instances generate a value and name randomly.

```
self.gem_list = []
for i in range(self.gem_count):
    g = Gem()
    print(g)
    self.gem_list.append(g)

print('---')

for x in self.gem_list: 
    print(x)
```

gives the output:

```
10 g.p. Tiger Eye
35 g.p. Jasper
10 g.p. Rhodochrosite
120 g.p. Coral
35 g.p. Lapis Lazuli
14 g.p. Malachite
---
14 g.p. Tiger Eye
35 g.p. Jasper
14 g.p. Rhodochrosite
120 g.p. Coral
35 g.p. Lapis Lazuli
14 g.p. Malachite
```

It appears that some of the values are being set to others, but I don't understand how this could be happening when all that I'm doing is appending the instances created within the loop to a list.

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

I'm basically wondering if the problem lies in assuming that each of the instances created in the loop are unique, or rather if it may stem from something elsewhere in my code.

Edit:
Here is the Gem class

```
class Gem():
    def __init__(self):
        base_idx = generateBaseValueIdx()
        base_idx, value_mod = modifyBaseValue(base_idx)

        self.value = BASE_VALUES[base_idx]

        #determine type of gem
        self.name, self.group = gemType(self.value)

        #modified value
        self.value.quantity = roundDownToNearest(self.value.quantity * value_mod, 1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} ({})'.format(self.value,self.name,self.group)

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.value < other.value
```

Comment: Can you show `Gem` class?

Comment: You seem to be using (and mutating) shared objects for the attributes of a `Gem` instance.

Comment: Right, that's what it seems to me as well. But I can't figure out why/how the value objects are being shared.

Comment: Well, `self.value = BASE_VALUES[base_idx]` is pretty obviously using a shared value.

Comment: Ah, you're right. BASE_VALUES is a tuple of Coin instances (which contain the currency type and quantity). I meant for it to be a constant, but I must be actually changing the values of the instances in the tuple with the self.value.quantity = ... line. I'll look into it.

Comment: Yes that was it. Setting self.value = copy(BASE_VALUES[base_idx]) solved the problem.